# Java script In rdlc

Tags: javascript, iframe, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

i am using java script in rdl to open another page in a tab when we click a particular row in rdlc,i used the following code for that purpose

```
="javascript:void(window.parent.$('#tt').tabs('add',{title: 'New Company',content:'<iframe src=\x22../Company/Company/CompanyDetail?id=5\x22 </iframe>',closable: true}))"
```

i hard coded the value of "id".now i want to pass a parameter like "Parameters!company_ID.Value" instead of "5"..i already tried many ways.but nothing worked out..please suggest a suitable method

Comment: http://jeffprom.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/use-javascript-to-open-a-second-ssrs-report-window/

Comment: while using window.open new page will be open outside the application in a new page..is there anyway to modify the code i gave ?

Comment: Opening in a window or tab is a browser property. You need to change individual user browser setting to open in a tab instead of a new window. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript